# Am I in the right place here if I teach programming?

Tags: discussion

I am a software developer in the industry, but one of my secondary functions is training apprenticeship developers on the job.

In Germany the apprenticeship is a secondary education that comes after high school, and is done by a larger part of the population than going to university. There are a couple of official jobs you can learn that way, and software development is one of them. As an apprentice, you find a company that employs you, and then work there for three years. Every couple of weeks, you attend a vocational school that is not unlike a community college. I myself have done that some time ago, and I am now a certified trainer for the job part.

I once in a while read things here on the CS educators SE, and while most of the things I see tend to deal with university level stuff, a lot of the concepts and the general ideas overlap with what I do. Parts of what I train are computer science (maybe more basic), and the part that deals with dealing with people definitely overlap. It's just not academic.

Am I in the right place to participate actively here?

Comment: Yes, CSEducators is where you want to ask questions. You can also visit our main chat room if you want more guidance. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/the-classroom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**100% yes**, what you are describing is the reason that this community was created.

Our scope encompasses the instruction of both software engineering/development and strict computer science.  Being affiliated with a school is **not** a requirement.  (There is even a tag for [self-learning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning), which is fine as long as it is about how to learn material, and not about the material itself.)

We have had a few questions from folks teaching in industry so far, and a huge number of answers from the development community, so I believe that you will be in good company here.

Welcome to CSE!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have brought up, in the past, in the chat, that the site is getting too focused around university. We need more primary school, and industry question. So yes please, help us to correct the bias.

Comment: That's really weird. My subjective perception is that this site is focused on high school and undergraduate-level questions are rare.

Comment: @Giles I would not disagree. I think it is mainly HS and UG (in some order). I would like to see more primary school questions (though I don't teach it.).